# ArcGIS Desktop: How to animate the graduated symbol of a shape file according to the column wise data of the attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, attribute-table, animation

I am new to ArcGIS Desktop, and I am trying to animate the attribute table of a shapefile in a column wise fashion. In the below picture, I have columns of attribute table representing 10 different times

[image]

Right now, the ArcGIS shows the graduated symbol for the column t1 (picture below).

[image]

How can I animate the graduated symbol such that it represent each column (t1, t2, t3...) at a time?

Comment: This topic is manifested as a rather large chunk of documentation, one block of which [starting here]()https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/time/about-visualizing-temporal-data.htm). Please [Edit] the question to specify what you have tried, and what problem you have encountered. You should also also specify the exact release of software involved, since "ArcGIS Desktop" spans both ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro, which have different features in this regard.

Comment: Your dataset appears to not a time field to animate over?